# PHP Как правильно прописать переменную в строку&

Tags: php

Всем привет, не сильно силен в php, столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Как правильно нужно прописать переменную `$kategoriya` в строке

```
$query = new WP_Query('post_type=catalog&category_name=' . $kategoriya);
```

Comment: Правильно же прописали

Comment: если хотите вставить прям внутрь строки, то используйте двойные кавычки